# How to make mouse wheel as default point in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mouseevent, mousewheel

By default, all the pointer events are absorbed by the mouse itself. I want to change this in such a way that all these events will be handled by mouse wheel(and not the mouse itself). For example:

pointerexited: when mouse wheel rotate and exit one button in uwp.

note: my final objective is to disable all other sources of pointer and just keep the mouse wheel.

Comment: Is this for an app in the Store or for private distribution?

Comment: for private distribution

Comment: There are Restricted Capabilities to block input and inject input into your app, so in theory you could do that... But there isn't much documentation that I know of. Might be best to focus on specific questions.